# Adding an additional template to an existing project errors out

Tags: django

I posted something last week and I haven't been able to get an answer.  I'm using the following github project for using filters.  I'm having trouble getting any additional templates to work.

https://github.com/sibtc/simple-django-filter

When I attempt to add a new template to the project or view I get the following error when trying to navigate to search because the template has a reference to a new page called results,which the results of the filter will have a POST occur:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or patter
n name.
```

When trying to add the url for the view for results using the following, I still get the error above:

```
url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
```

I also include from . import views in the urls.py

I'm adding an empty view for results:

```
def results(request):


    return render(request, 'results.html', args)
```

I'm thinking it has to do something with how the directory structure of the simple filter app is setup and how i'm doing things.

I added the project URL below as well:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from mysite.search.filters import UserFilter

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^search/$', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=UserFilter, template_name='search/user_list.html'), name='search'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^results/', include('app_name.urls')),

]
```

Here are is application urls.py

```
  from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from mysite.search.filters import UserFilter
from . import views



app_name = 'search'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

Added installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'mysite',
    'mysite.search',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

Added directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are missing out the namespace, e.g. `myapp:results`.

Comment: Would I need a namespace since there is only one project and one application?  I added my project URL above.  Where would I put the namespace in the URL for the view?  I'm looking at the following documentation:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/  .  Would this be an application namespace or instanced namespace?

Comment: I posted my project urls.py and application urls.py  would that require a name space?

Comment: It's a good idea to set `app_name` to namespace your application's urls, but it's not required. The problem here is that your application's urls is not being included anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *include* your applications URLs in the project's urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^search/$', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=UserFilter, template_name='search/user_list.html'), name='search'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls'),
]
```

You should also remove the urls like `admin` from the application's urls, otherwise they will be available at `/admin/` and `/myapp/admin/`.

```
app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

It's recommended, but not required, to set `app_name` in the application's `urls.py`. If you do this, then you'll have to use it when reversing the URLs, e.g. `'myapp:results'` instead of `'results'`.

Comment: I added your suggestions to my applicaiton urls.py as shown above in the edit, but it still gives me the same error message.  Am I confusing project and app in the github above?

Comment: You should put the include in the project's urls, not the application's urls. It might be worth going through the Django tutorial -- you create an app and include it in the very first part, which might help you understand these ideas better.

Comment: I went through the tutorial and created my own app that works great.  I think the issue i'm having is my project urls.py and application urls.py were backwards.  However, when I try to add the include(app_name.urls) to my project urls.py it gives this error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'urls'  I'll update the above what i have for project and application urls.py

Comment: The easiest way to use include is with a string, like I have in my answer: `include('myapp.urls')`. The `app_name` should be in the *app*’s urls. You appear to have it in the project’s urls.

Comment: When I move app_name = 'search' to the project URL it states app_name is not defined, because the include is in the project url as you said above.  I also took it out of the quotes because those are for the module in that instance and it displays ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_name'

Comment: As I said, use a string with `include`, e.g. `include('myapp.urls')`. If your app is named search, then use `include('search.urls')`.

Comment: I am doing exactly as you stated I updated the code as above and it gives no module named 'app_name' when using the quotes.

Comment: I didn’t say to use `'app_name.urls'` anywhere. My examples are for an app named `myapp`. If your app is named `search` you should replace `myapp` with `search`.

Comment: That works if I hard code it.  I'm sorry I was confused by the answers above having app_name = ...  I updated my code above, now it gives me a runtime error related to the model RuntimeError: Model class search.models.AllEEActive doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.  I updated my installed apps.

Comment: That’s a completely separate error so would be better as a new question

Comment: I fixed that error by adding django-filters to my list of installed apps, but now i'm still getting the same error I started with django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.  Any chance you can try to open the filters app in the github above and try to post the results of the filter to the new view/template?   I added my directory structure above.

Comment: Looking at my directory structure it appears I have search in there two times, which one should be the correct one?

Comment: No, I can't download and run your code. If you have `search` in the same directory as `manage.py` then you should use `search` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. If `search` is in the same directory as `settings.py` then you need `mysite.search` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The first is more common but it's up to you.

Comment: If you added app_name = 'search' to your urls.py, then you need the namespace `'search:results'` as I originally suggested.