# no module named search after adding project url

Tags: django

I've had the pleasure to work with somebody yesterday on the issue with my urls here [Adding an additional template to an existing project errors out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014711/adding-an-additional-template-to-an-existing-project-errors-out/49015022?noredirect=1#comment85058017_49015022), but after trying everything suggested i'm still in the same situation.

My project is named mysite and my application is search.

It was suggested to add the following to my project urls.py

```
url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
```

When doing so I'm given the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'search'.

My project urls.py is the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from mysite.search.filters import UserFilter


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^search/$', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=UserFilter, template_name='search/user_list.html'), name='search'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
]
```

I'm attempting to add the following to my app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from mysite.search.filters import UserFilter
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

I have an empty view for results defined as

```
def results(request):

    return render(request, 'results.html')
```

When I try to add the following POST to my form for the results it gives me the error in the first post.  When I have the results url in my app.urls.py

```
  <form action = "{% url 'results' %}" form method = "POST">
```

This is what my current application structure looks like.   Please help get me on the right track.  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `search` directory is in your `mysite` directory (the one that includes `settings.py`. That means you should include `mysite.search.urls` (just as you use `mysite.search` in your import and `INSTALLED_APPS`).

```
from mysite.search.filters import UserFilter

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^search/', include('mysite.search.urls')),
]
```

If your `search` directory was in your project directory (the one that includes `manage.py`, then you would remove `mysite` from the import, `include()` and `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
from search.filters import UserFilter

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thank you Alasdair, that was my issue.  Once again, i'm greeted with   File "C:\python\dsssecurity\mysite\search\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Employee
ImportError: cannot import name 'Employee', but I guess that is another issue itself.

Comment: Does doing it this way with mysite.search.urls change from django.contrib.auth.models import ModelName?

Comment: That's a completely separate issue - `django.contrib.auth.models` does not contain a model named `Employee`, so that import is incorrect.

Comment: Changing it to from .models import Employee instead of django.contrib.auth.models fixed that issue.   Contrib.auth.models used to work before I added include('mysite.search.urls')

Comment: The import was always invalid. Before you added the include the module was not loaded, so you didn’t get the error, but the urls were not included.